# Eloquent delete does not work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need your help, delete doesn´t work.

```js
public function postUnregisterPushNotifications()
    {
        try {
            $serial_usr = JWTAuth::getPayload(JWTAuth::getToken())->get('sub');
            $device_token = Input::get('device_token');
   $topic = null;
            $device = Device::where('user_id', $serial_usr)->where('token', $device_token);
            $device-> delete();
            JWTAuth::setToken(JWTAuth::getToken())->invalidate();
            return ws_response(false, 'Unregister Notification success', '', 200);

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return ws_response(true, null, 'ERROR ' . $ex->getCode() . '! ' . $ex->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }
```

The insert to the table works but the delete when I logout does not delete from the table

Comment: Need some more background here. Have you stepped through to see if `$device` is correctly fetched from the database? Do you get an error message?

Comment: `dd($device);` to see if it really fetched from the db

Comment: I think you are missing the `get()` method on `$device = Device::where('user_id', $serial_usr)->where('token', $device_token);` It should be `$device = Device::where('user_id', $serial_usr)->where('token', $device_token)->get();` so it can return something, otherwise is just an Eloquent call, not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing here is the `->get()` method which fetches from the database and then `->delete()` method works on the selection.

This should be how your code snippet should look like.

```
public function postUnregisterPushNotifications()
{
    try {
        $serial_usr = JWTAuth::getPayload(JWTAuth::getToken())->get('sub');
        $device_token = Input::get('device_token');
        $topic = null;
        $device = Device::where('user_id', $serial_usr)->where('token', $device_token)->get();
        $device->delete();
        JWTAuth::setToken(JWTAuth::getToken())->invalidate();
        return ws_response(false, 'Unregister Notification success', '', 200);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return ws_response(true, null, 'ERROR ' . $ex->getCode() . '! ' . $ex->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```